# qt - creator - how to maximize the widget screen

Tags: user-interface, qt, qt-creator

I am tryimng to make a UI. But in qt, the window size is too short, I want to work in a separate windows like photoshop. Here I am posting the picture. I want to see the middle window(i rounded it by rose color) in full screen size. Can anybody help me? 
[image]

**EDIT:**
     If I want to create a full screen application, How can I position the widgets in it. It's possible dragging a widget inside a scroll bared window,but is not user friendly. I want it to work like photoshop, like separate windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have more space to work on the design of your widgets, you can open QtDesigner separately and maximize the design area. Panels can be closed and undocked.

Now if you want to maximized only the central widget, there is a trick:

1. Create a custom widget and work on it in QtDesigner. You will be able to put it in near full screen by increasing its size
2. Set your custom widget as central widget in your GUI application.

---

**Previous answer before edit:**

Hi, If you want to view your widget in fullsreen mode, you can call the ShowFullScreen function. If what you want is to maximize the widget, you can call the ShowMaximized function.

Comment: I think what he means is a maximized view of his widget while editing it in Qt creator. Not the compiled version of it.

Comment: @Exa
Yes, as you said I want the maximized view of that widget. See the edited question